# Get Github Pages Site found in Google Search Results

Tags: github-pages, google-search

I have a site built with Jekyll Now on GitHub and I want it to appear in a google search. If I just google my GitHub username followed by 'GitHub' and 'io', it does not find my site. How do I get google to find my site in a google search?

Comment: In case you already use Google Analytics on your site (which can be trivially achieved by adding `google_analytics: <YOURTAG>` to a `_config.yml` for e.g. `jekyll-theme-cayman`), you can use that for verification with Google Search. It should be detected automatically when entering your site's URL.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You have to create a Google Search Console account and add your page, then typically you just drop a "marker" file in the root (Search Console generates this) so that Google can confirm you really own the page.

[Google Search Console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home)

[Instructions](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6332964?hl=en&ref_topic=4564315)

(Since the instructions are long and have many links to sub-steps, I'm only providing the link.)

Also, if you're going to use a registered domain name, set that up *before* you register the site for search.

(Edit: Technically you don't *have* to do this, sooner or later Google will find you... but this will give your content a much higher-quality score.)

Comment: Have you seen or had problems with the status: "This page is not in the index, but not because of an error" ... "Coverage: Page with redirect"?  Is that a limitation of using GitHub pages?  Thanks.

Comment: Also see [this blog](https://victor2code.github.io/blog/2019/07/04/jekyll-github-pages-appear-on-Google.html)

Comment: Has anyone gotten this to work?  Ive waited like a month and still nothing in the search console.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, google finds all website and index them. Sometimes, it's takes time to crawl the new website.

But, you can do this thing manually by following these steps:

1. Go to Google [Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console)
2. Add the website as your [property](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592?hl=en)
3. Then, verify your property that you're the owner of this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

It can take a few days before the site is indexed by search engines. Google for [google index site](https://www.google.nl/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=google+index+site) and you will find quite a lot of information about the process and how it can be speed up.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

1. Go to Google console: https://search.google.com/search-console/welcome
2. Paste your GitHub website address in the "URL prefix" window.
3. Download the HTML verification file.
4. Upload such file in your website.
5. IMPORTANT: Wait for some time and then click on "verify" in back in Google console.

Comment: The meta tag worked faster for me